# how to import and use an external library into a go project

Tags: go, aerospike

I'm newbie to go lang and i created an hello project with intellij.

now I want to use external lib.
for example:

connect into aerospike using:

http://www.aerospike.com/docs/client/go/examples.html

what I don't understand is how to import it into solution.
I've run from the terminal the command:

```
go get github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go
```

but I don't see any result in the project and don't understand which object to use from my main method.

can you help?

Comment: Start with the [example](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go#usage).

Comment: i just get package github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go/...: cannot download, $GOPATH must not be set to $GOROOT. For more details see: 'go help gopath'

Comment: Read [How to write Go code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html).

Comment: Please add the error to the original question; don't make people read the comments to figure out what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 7):

The `go get` command downloads the dependency to your $GOPATH dir from where it is accessible by the go compiler when building your sources. Now you simply have to import the package by its full name `import github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go`